# How struct was passed to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

In the following code, I tried to pass a simple `struct` variable to `func()` function, and see what would happen to the original `struct` variable when `func()` returned.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
struct student
{
    char name[8];
};
void func(student a)
{
    a.name[1] = 'Z';
}
int main()
{
    student a;
    strcpy(a.name, "abcde");
    func(a);
    cout << a.name;
}
```

It prints out `abcde`, not `aZcde`, which means the original `a` was unchanged after `func()` returned.

So rather than passing members by value( and pass address when it comes to `char[]`), it seems that the `struct student` was passed as a whole to the `func()`.

I'm quite confused if this is true, because it seems this violates some principles. I have originally thought that `struct`, like many other practices, would let its member decide how to pass to a function. And  principle two just like `built-in array` which may take up lots of memory, it should pass a pointer, rather all the contents in memory, so should `struct`, especially when struct may have a couple of `built-in array` members.

Just don't the details how `struct` is passed to a function.

Comment: When you say "principle", do you mean "baseless prejudice I've been harbouring without ever checking"?

Comment: Everything is value by default. Passing an array **directly** is really the only special case, where it decays to a pointer.

Comment: Yes, I believe OP has some misconceptions about function calls and parameter passing. The answer regarding passing value/reference/pointer is correct but lacks depth. I suggest the OP tries an introductory course in CS instead of trying to learn it through stackoverflow

Comment: I've added some brief explanation on why c++ doesn't automatically pass parameters in the most efficient way.

Comment: I've got some misconceptions here and jumped to the conclusion arbitrarily, sorry about that. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it should pass a pointer, rather all the contents in memory,

No, all of the elements of the array will be copied. You don't declare a copy ctor by yourself, and the behaviour of implicitly-defined copy constructor is provided as follows.

According to the stardard, $12.8/15 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy] (bold by me)

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X
> performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members.
>
> Let x be either
> the parameter of the constructor. Each base or non-static data member
> is copied/moved in the manner appropriate to its type:
>
> (15.1) — if the
> member is an array, **each element** is direct-initialized with the
> corresponding subobject of x;

Comment: Upvoted. Have no idea that when a struct is passed by value, a copy constructor is called. I think that exactly solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to pass parameters to functions in C++:

1 - by value (default)

2- by reference

3- by pointer (which is technically by value, but with the special twist that the value passed is an address)

`func(student a)` is by value, as you didn't specified anything special. What happens is that you create a local variable `a`, in which you'll copy the content of `student a` (but the one in `main`). Once the function terminates, the local `a` is destroyed, and so your change didn't affect anything.

But if you wanted to change the value of the struct `a` in main, you'd need to pass via reference or via a pointer. Example:

Pointer:

in main... `func(&a)` ... and your function `func` would be

```
void func(student* a) {
    a->name[1] = 'Z';
}
```

If you'd rather want to do it via reference, no change in the main, but your function `func` would be:

```
void func(student& a) {
    a.name[1] = 'Z';
}
```

For more explanation, [go here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm) in the "Function Arguments" section.

**Edit:** In response to OP saying

> many other practices, would let its member decide how to pass to a function. And principle two just like built-in array which may take up lots of memory, it should pass a pointer, rather all the contents in memory [...] Just don't (explain) the details how struct is passed to a function.

In the C/C++ mentality, almost nothing is done in the background. It's meant to give the power to the programmer to decide which way is better for a specific case. The down side is that it makes it a little more cryptic/difficult for new comers.

Therefore, passing a `struct` as a parameter, without using `&` or `*` (aka pointers or references) will make it pass by value. C++ won't do some magic behind your back, and it'll be consistent.

Comment: What is the struct was defined like this

`struct student { char *a; };`  [We will assume that space is allocated for `a` using the `new` operator before the `strcpy`.] In that case the OP will get the behavior he expected. But your explanation doesn't adequately cover his example because the struct is still passed by value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this case the copy constructor explanation better solves my problem. Still upvoted for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Yes, when you pass an object by value it calls the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're seeing the C++ default copy constructor in action.

The parameter is copied, and since it is an array constant (a[8]) the entire array is copied, not a pointer to it.

Prefer to pass by reference (f(student& s)).